# Remove NaN from all variables in table in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a table with many variables and some of the entries have `NaN`´s. I would like to replace all `NaN` with 0. I am able to find the `NaN`´s with this:

```
T = table(rand(200,1),[rand(199,1);NaN],rand(200,1));
Index = varfun(@isnan,T);
```

However, when I try to apply the index to the table, T:

```
T(Index)=0;
```

I get the following error:

```
You can not subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting requires both row and variable subscripts.
```

Is there an easy solution to this, or do I need to change the from table to a matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues seems to be that `Index` is still a table and that you always need to use `row` and `column` as indices for a table. I tried the following code (without the intermediate table `Index`) and it works, although I'm not sure this is the best solution.

```
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(T),find(isnan(T{:,:})));
T(i,j) = {0};
```

Comment: Thanks! The final assignment of 0 is very slow! Do you know why and if there is a faster way?

Comment: Not really, I don't have much experience with tables. However, can you try `T{i,j} = 0`? Maybe to cell generation is slow.

Comment: Than it seems to be an speed-issue of directly indexing of tables-elements. In this case, using matrices instead of tables seems to be the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert to an array, do the substitution with logical indexing, and then go back to a table:

```
T = table(rand(200,1),[rand(199,1);NaN],rand(200,1));
t = table2array(T);
t(isnan(t)) = 0;
T = array2table(t, 'VariableNames', T.Properties.VariableNames);
```

Also, consider using just the array if that's acceptable for you (without converting from or to a table).

Comment: I also think an array is the best solution when working only with numerical data.